# D3 Multi Series Line Chart

Tags: html, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 line chart. I have copied the code from the block builder and replaced with my data. Although the code is working but its not showing the labels when i hover the line.

I want to basically get the label details when I hover over the line.

Original Block https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91

Regards,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 12px Helvetica; 
}

.axis line {
  fill: red;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

</style>

<body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 80},
    width = 630 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.Year,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });



var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(10)
    .innerTickSize(2)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d ;})
    .ticks(10)
    .innerTickSize(2.5)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavjaitly/f1339c2bc02857afdf65b8d572dc31e5/raw/72ad1af2eacc86575649ae015b433aacb37f3854/US.and.SF.Crimerate.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Year"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.Year);
  });

  var companies = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d) {
    return {date: d.date, price: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });



  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(companies, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return            v.price; }); }),
    d3.max(companies, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return            v.price; }); })
    ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Crime Rate per 10,000");

  svg.append("line")
        .attr(
        {
            "class":"horizontalGrid",
            "x1" : 0,
            "x2" : width,
            "y1" : y(0),
            "y2" : y(0),
            "fill" : "none",
            "shape-rendering" : "crispEdges",
            "stroke" : "black",
            "stroke-width" : "1px",
            "stroke-dasharray": ("3, 3")
        });


  var company = svg.selectAll(".company")
      .data(companies)
        .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "company");



  var path = svg.selectAll(".company").append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name)
                                         });

var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];
console.log(totalLength);

   d3.select(path[0][0])
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0] ) 
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
      .transition()
        .duration(15000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

   d3.select(path[0][1])
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1] )
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
      .transition()
        .duration(15000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

});

   var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

   var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.Year);
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
      .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })
      .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
          });

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            console.log(width/mouse[0])
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.Year; }).right;
                idx = bisect(d.values, xYear);

            var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null;

            while (true){
              target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
              pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
              if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
              }
              if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
              else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
              else break; //position found
            }

            d3.select(this).select('text')
              .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";
          });
      });



</script>
```

Comment: Do you notice any difference between the data used in the reference code and the data that you use? Any different column names that is used in the code to set the domains?

Comment: Hey Shashank, Thanks for helping. Yes I noticed but i can't find those variables ("Airbus" & "Boeing") in the code so i dont know where I should make the changes. @Shashank

Comment: Nah. The only column being used in the code is the "date" column. Anyway, I'll post the answer and that'll clear it up.

Comment: @Shashank Thanks a lot. You are the best. Apologies I wish I could have catched that.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If you could accept the answer, the issue can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: @Shashank. I am actually trying to add one more feature. I want to add hover details so if i hover any line it shows the crime rate in both the lines. Could you help on this as well sorry for asking for so many things

Comment: @Shashank. I have updated the code and the question.

Comment: That's a new requirement and it should be posted as a new question with the reference block, the code you've tried with details on where exactly you're stuck. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Minor change:

The "date" column being used in the code is based on the reference data. In your case, it should be changed to "Year".

Changing:

`color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));`

to

`color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Year"; }));`

and

```
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
```

to

```
d.date = parseDate(d.Year);
```

Here's a new block:

https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/8d4aa05b7cf14d15099e0a0c47476f0e/d0c76a98426d7524b97f5c815b05c3d91d5b6dd0

Hope this helps.